# How do I work out which index I need to create for this multi-join multi-condition query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I think I lack a basic understanding of how to structure an index for complex queries.  Given the below query, what would be the optimum index to have on table `PHOTOS`?  I feel it should be possible to just *know* without having to do lots of trial and error (which trust me, I have...)

This is the index I have at the moment, which gives me `Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort`.  I'd like to get rid of the temporary/filesort bits, if possible.

```
testIndex: photoTypeID, photoID, photographerID, shootID, timeAdded
```

And here's the query (it's more complex in reality but I've stripped it down to the minimum relevant `PHOTOS`-index-related stuff:

```
SELECT 
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

PH.photoID

FROM      PHOTOS                PH
JOIN      PHOTO_TYPES           PT  ON  PT.photoTypeID     = PH.photoTypeID
LEFT JOIN PHOTO_LINKS           PL  ON  PL.photoID         = PH.photoID
LEFT JOIN PAYPAL_ITEMS          PI  ON  PI.photoID         = PH.photoID
LEFT JOIN PHOTOGRAPHER_PRODUCTS PP  ON  PP.photographerID  = PH.photographerID

WHERE PH.shootID = 1234

GROUP BY PH.photoID

ORDER BY PH.timeAdded DESC

LIMIT 0, 100;
```

EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys       key             key_len ref             rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE          PH      ref     PRIMARY,testIndex   testIndex       4   const               80632   100         Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          PT      eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY         1   PH.photoTypeID      1       100         Using index
1   SIMPLE          PL      ref     photoID             photoID         4   PH.photoID          1       100         Using index
1   SIMPLE          PCI     ref     photoID             photoID         5   PH.photoID,const    1       100         Using index
1   SIMPLE          PP      ref     photographerID      photographerID  4   PH.photographerID   4       100         Using where; Using index
```

Comment: are you quite sure that you got your index/query exactly as it is? It seems hard to digest that the testIndex (in the way you have defined) will be used on the PH table.

Comment: Yep, just checked and confirmed!

Comment: pretty same because testIndex doesn't begin with shootId and that explain says 'const'

Answer (score 0):

You need a composite `INDEX(shootID, photoID)`, as I describe [*in my indexing cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/).

- `shootID` is `=` in the `WHERE`, so it comes first
- Since all the `WHERE` is handled, we can move on...
- Add all the `GROUP BY`, namely `photoID`
- But we have to stop here because the `ORDER BY` is not the same as the `GROUP BY`.

So... The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` will necessitate a temp and filesort.

But... There is another problem (probably):  When you do `JOIN`, that (usually) inflates the number of rows.  The 'obvious' cure is to do a `GROUP BY` do deflate it.  But any aggregates (and `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`) will count the inflated value.  Hence the 'problem'.

So...  Let's try to get the count *before* doing the `JOINs`.  But wait!  Why have the joins?  You are not fetching anything from them.  And, since they are (mostly) `LEFT JOINs`, you are not using those `JOINs` for filtering.

Well, I can't figure out the intent of the query, but I will give you a tip that *might* help.

```
SELECT  photoID
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                photoID, photoTypeID, photographerID
            FROM  PHOTOS
            WHERE  shootID = 1234
            ORDER BY  PH.timeAdded DESC
            LIMIT  0, 100 
    ) AS PH
    JOIN  PHOTO_TYPES PT  ON PT.photoTypeID = PH.photoTypeID
    LEFT JOIN  PHOTO_LINKS PL  ON PL.photoID = PH.photoID
    LEFT JOIN  PAYPAL_ITEMS PI  ON PI.photoID = PH.photoID
    LEFT JOIN  PHOTOGRAPHER_PRODUCTS PP  ON PP.photographerID = PH.photographerID
    ORDER BY  PH.timeAdded DESC;
```

That version will need `INDEX(shootID, timeAdded)`.  It it gives you the correct answer, it should be a lot faster and not use a tmp or filesort.